# XOR wrong result , escaping char

Tags: c++, xor

I am trying to xor a small string , it works . When I try to use the XORed string , I can't even compile it.

```
 string str = "MyNameIsMila";
 string str_xored = "2*&.8"'*"; //you can't escape this or the result be be different 
 //Enc:2*&.8"'*:
 //Dec:MyNameIsMila:
```

I tried to escape the string , but then I have another result at the end.
Any good direction for this ?
Output after escaping:

```
//Enc:yamesila:
//Dec:2*&.8"'*:
```

Hoped to get MyNameIsMila back.

The function looks like :

```
 string encryptDecrypt(string toEncrypt) {
     char key = 'K'; //Any char will work
     string output = toEncrypt;   
     for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.size(); i++)
         output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key;
     return output;
 }
```

Comment: You get problems because that's not a *string*. `"2*&.8\"'*"` is a string.

Comment: Last I checked, strings go in quotes. The problem is that your XORd string isn't all printable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg escaping the string will get wrong results

Comment: If you don't want a different result, what's the question? And if you do want a different result, why can't you escape the string?

Comment: `string str_xored = "2*&.8\"'*";`. you insert **"** in strings with `\\`

Comment: If you use XOR decoding/encoding, the end result should be the same size as the input, if the input is 12 characters, the output should be as well., Start debugging from that angle. My guess is that the XOR operation creates some unprintable characters, that you forget.

Comment: "escaping the string will get wrong results". then you have to find out where the bug is. It makes no sense to insist that escaping is the culprit. Escaping is a necessary condition to have a valid program.

Comment: The XOR-ing is very likely to produce unprintable characters. As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/djFCHF), yours does. (ASCII 2, 5, and 6 are all control characters.)

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks , the best answer here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've 2 things to say:

> 1: The value of a string needs to be between 2 -> ""

```
 string str_xored = 2*&.8"'*;   //this is not a valid syntax = error

 //valid
 string str_xored = "2*&.8";
 str += '"';
 str += "'*";
```

> 2: In your case I would use iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//please don't use "using namespace std;"

 std::string encryptDecrypt(std::string toEncrypt) {
     char key = 'K';            //Any char will work
     std::string output = "";   //needs to be   empty   

     for (auto i = toEncrypt.begin(); i != toEncrypt.end(); i++) {
        output += *i ^ key;     //*i holds the current character to see how
                                //an iterator works have a look at my link
     }
     return output;
 }


int main() {

    std::string str = encryptDecrypt("Hello...!");

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here have a look at the (string) iterator:

> [Link 1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/begin/)
>
> [Link 2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/)

If you think iterators are too difficult then use your

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
    //CODE
}
```

for()-loop

Comment: More helpful the the other comments. I know that a variable needs to be between two " .. I can't use your valid string getting error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char *' and 'const char *')
         string str = "2*&.8" + '"' + "'*"; .

Answer (score 0):

You can't treat xored strings like normal strings!

```
value ^ same_value == 0
```

Treat them as normal containers instead.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator, typename Key>
void perform_xor(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, OutputIterator out, Key const &key) {
    std::transform(begin, end, out, [key](auto &&value) { 
        return value ^ key;
    });
}

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char test[] = "(2*&.8\"\'*";

    perform_xor(begin(test), end(test), begin(test), '&');
    copy(begin(test), end(test), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); 

    cout << endl;

    perform_xor(begin(test), end(test), begin(test), '&');
    copy(begin(test), end(test), ostream_iterator<char>(cout)); 

    return 0;
}
```

see: http://ideone.com/ryoNp5

Comment: A `std::string` can be used.  However the XOR operation may produce character values that are not printable.